# How can I verify my consumerkey? (error 8)

Tags: sandbox, evernote

I'm trying to connect to the sandbox version of Evernote. I get an error 8 every time I call userStore.authenticate(), on the field "consumerKey." This happens with either of the two keys Evernote has sent me in email.

Any tips on how to debug this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [UserStore.authenticateToLongSession](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/UserStore.html#Fn_UserStore_authenticateLongSession)? It's not available to third party developers. You have to go through the OAuth flow to authenticate to the service. See [this section](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php).

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer. How would I be using that if it's not available to 3rd party developers? I don't even have that method in my Thrift file - which leads me to believe I have an old version. Is OAuth the only way to authenticate with Evernote for 3rd party developers?

Comment: Yes, OAuth is the only way to authenticate for most of the 3rd party developers.